# Broadcast across pandas MultiIndex level even if index values happen to agree

Tags: pandas, multi-index, array-broadcasting

This one has me stumped. I have two `pd.Series` `s` and `t` as follows:

```
Common  Level s
Foo     a          1
        b          2
Name: s, dtype: int64
```

```
Common  Level t
Foo     A          10
        B          20
Name: t, dtype: int64
```

`pandas` lets me add these and broadcasts across the common level `'Common'`

Input:

```
s + t
```

Output:

```
Common  Level s  Level t
Foo     a        A          11
                 B          21
        b        A          12
                 B          22
dtype: int64
```

Consider now another `pd.Series` `u` where the index *labels* happen to agree with those of `s`

```
Common  Level u
Foo     a          100
        b          200
Name: u, dtype: int64
```

In other words, we have `(s.index.values == u.index.values).all()` returns `True`. Because of this, `pandas` no longer broadcasts

Input:

```
s + u
```

Output:

```
Common  Level s
Foo     a          101
        b          202
dtype: int64
```

even though `s.index.names` and `u.index.names` disagree.

Lastly, if the order is changed but not the labels, such as for `v`:

```
Common  Level v
Foo     b          1000
        a          2000
Name: v, dtype: int64
```

so that `s.index.values` and `v.index.values` don't agree outright, then broadcasting happens.

Input:

```
s + v
```

Output:

```
Common  Level s  Level v
Foo     a        b          1001
                 a          2001
        b        b          1002
                 a          2002
dtype: int64
```

**My question**: How can I add `s` and `u` such that `pandas` still broadcasts? (For my particular application, I am actually interested in elementwise-and `s & u`, not the sum `s + u`.)

---

**Code**

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2],
              index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                  [('Foo', 'a'), ('Foo', 'b')],
                  names=['Common', 'Level s']), name='s')

t = pd.Series([10, 20],
              index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                  [('Foo', 'A'), ('Foo', 'B')],
                  names=['Common', 'Level t']), name='t')

u = pd.Series([100, 200],
              index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                  [('Foo', 'a'), ('Foo', 'b')],
                  names=['Common', 'Level u']), name='u')

v = pd.Series([1000, 2000],
              index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                  [('Foo', 'b'), ('Foo', 'a')],
                  names=['Common', 'Level v']), name='v')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that is called to normalise indexes of Series and DataFrames for broadcasting is [`align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.align.html). This method is called internally to get the new indexes, we can see this with:

```
left, right = s.align(t, join='outer', level=None, copy=False)

# left
Common  Level s  Level t
Foo     a        A          1
                 B          1
        b        A          2
                 B          2
Name: s, dtype: int64
# right
Common  Level s  Level t
Foo     a        A          10
                 B          20
        b        A          10
                 B          20
Name: t, dtype: int64
```

Notice that this call will produce the "non-broadcasted" values when the indexes are equal since outer join produces a single level:

```
left, right = s.align(u, join='outer', level=None, copy=False)

# left
Common  Level s
Foo     a          1
        b          2
Name: s, dtype: int64

# right
Common  Level u
Foo     a          100
        b          200
Name: u, dtype: int64
```

---

If we want to force the levels to generate we can use the branch from [`_align_series`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.4/pandas/core/generic.py#L8694-L8699) for when indexes are non-equal:

> ```
> join_index, lidx, ridx = self.index.join(
>     other.index, how=join, level=level, return_indexers=True
> ) 
> left = self._reindex_indexer(join_index, lidx, copy)
> right = other._reindex_indexer(join_index, ridx, copy)
> ```

We can use [`Index.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.join.html) and `_reindex_indexer` to create the aligned Series:

```
join_index, lidx, ridx = s.index.join(
    u.index, how='outer', level=None, return_indexers=True
)
left = s._reindex_indexer(join_index, lidx, copy=False)
right = u._reindex_indexer(join_index, ridx, copy=False)
```

*Note: we are using a private method as there is no equivalent reindexer in the public API.

Now that we have aligned Series we can just do:

```
left + right
```

To get the results:

```
Common  Level s  Level u
Foo     a        a          101
                 b          201
        b        a          102
                 b          202
dtype: int64
```

---

If we wanted to avoid using the private method, we could also [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) to select values using index locations then [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html) to overwrite with the join index with appropriate labels:

```
join_index, lidx, ridx = s.index.join(
    u.index, how='outer', level=None, return_indexers=True
)
left = s.iloc[lidx].set_axis(join_index)
right = u.iloc[ridx].set_axis(join_index)
```

```
left + right
```

```
Common  Level s  Level u
Foo     a        a          101
                 b          201
        b        a          102
                 b          202
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Henry, thanks a lot for your answer. It's of course exactly what I was missing, and was a very nice surprise on the Friday night when I saw it.
I'm a bit opposed to the branch in `_align_series` which you pointed out for when index values agree and broadcasting doesn't happen. Because the `pd.Index`es in question have different `.name`s, I would like them to be treated as different and broadcasting to happen. Do you agree this is a reasonable position to hold? If so, is there somewhere I could voice my opinion on the matter?

Comment: You can always open an issue on the [pandas GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) if you believe this is unexpected/undesired behaviour.